# Unity, каким образом значения передаются в корутины?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В одном из уроков Unity learn я не понял одну вещь

```
public bool isGameActive;

void Start() {
   StartCoroutine(methodName);
   isGameActive = true;
}
IEnumerator methodName() {
   while(isGameActive) {
      Debug.Log("Y");  //никогда не выведется.
   }
}
```

Насколько я знаю, корутины это отдельный поток кода который срабатывает независимо от основного кода, я знаю что нужно присваивать значение переменной (isGameActive) до запуска корутины, но не понимаю почему так происходит, корутина останавливается сама после того как весь код будет выполнен в ней? хотя это перечит её функции, т.к. она должна вроде как повторятся непрерывно? Почему цикл while в корутине не срабатывает когда в основном потоке, переменной isGameActive задается значение true?

Comment: корутина - это не бесконечное выполнение чего-то... это такой же обычный метод, как и все.... только немножечко асинхронный.........всё.

Comment: "хотя это перечит её функции, т.к. она должна вроде как повторятся непрерывно?" --- нет.... вы где-то неправильно прочитали информацию

Comment: И чисто логически подумайте: если бы корутина была бы то, что крутится бесконечно (считаем как бесконечный цикл), то зачем внутри неё писать бесконечный цикл? нонсенс же

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Уже сам запутался, назначил корутине обязанности цикла While....  т.е.  по факту в данном коде запускается корутина, цикл while не отрабатывает, и корутина завершается!?

Comment: "цикл while не отрабатывает, и корутина завершается!" --- да

Comment: И корутина - это совсем не отдельный поток.

Answer (score 2):

- Во первых твоя корутина, тупо не корутина, потому что там нет прерывателя `yield`, на что тебе жалуется компилятор.
- Во вторых `StartCoroutine` принимает не имя метода а метод (с аргументами или без, но точно с скобками), на что компилятор тоже жалуется.
- Во третьих если цикл не сработал, то очевидно условия равняется `false`, корутина тут причем? `Debug.Log(isGameActive?"Y":"N");` перед циклом написать не пробывал? (реторический вопрос)

Корутина это не асинхронный метод, она в том-же потоке, о чем человеческим по белому написано в одном из первых обзацев [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), чтобы люди не выдумывали из каких мест знать. Следственно корутина реагирует на поля класса так-же как любой другой член класса.

Корутина ни чего ни кому не должна, как только код в методе закончился, кончилась и она сама. Если в ней нет цикла, это не её ошибка, она инструмент.